# XML parser for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

what's the best XML parser for parsing RSS feed type documents on the iPhone? Ive found a few samples on the internet but kept running into memory leak problems. any suggestions?

Comment: Memory leak problems?  Sure they are leaks and not just resource issues?  'select ain't broken?'

Comment: Maybe it's not the library that leaks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's built-in, `NSXMLParser` or `libxml` will require the least extra configuration.

If you want something that's more flexible and not event-based, try [TouchXML](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML).